# Cannot instantiate Identify from mini_magick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

Runing an example from here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick/MiniMagick/Tool:

```
version = MiniMagick::Tool::Identify.new { |b| b.version }
puts version
```

gives me:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MiniMagick::Tool
        from (irb):3
        from /home/branchito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in
<main>
1.9.3-p392 :004 >
```

while, `image = MiniMagick::Image.open fname` works without any problem!

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add on your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick', :git => 'https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick.git'
```

And:

```
require 'mini_magick'
```

At the top of the rb file where you are calling MiniMagick